# How to use flat shading in OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4?

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, glsl, opentk

I need to use flat shading in OpenTK.

I know there is a function in OpenGL (c++) called `glShadeModel`, and it was in OpenTK named (`GL.`)`ShadeModel`, but it's only in OpenTK.Graphics.ES11, and it's pretty old.

How can I do it using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4?

Comment: Use the `flat` [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glShadeModel` has been replaced by [Interpolation qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers).

However [`glShadeModel`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml) is still supportend in "desktop" OpenGL if you are using compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and are not using a shader program. This means you need to use the immediate mode and you have to draw by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences or fixed function attributes, without a shader program.

If you are using a core profile OpenGL context and/or a shader program and you want to achieve "flat" shading, you have to use the `flat` [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) for the vertex shader output variables. For instance:

Vertex shader

```c
#version 460

// [...]
in vec3 aColor;

flat out vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    vColor = aColor;

    // [...]
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
#version 460

flat in vec3 vColor;
out vec4 fragColor; 

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
}
```